# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

```
public TreeNode find(Integer data){
    if (this.data == data)
        return this;
    if (data < this.data && leftChild != null)
        return leftChild.find(data);

    if (rightChild != null)
        return rightChild.find(data);
    return null;
}
```

Hi there!, so I've done some research about similar problems and tried most of the suggestions and still nothing. I would like to know how to solve this problem because I've been stuck for a couple of hours now.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is the version of JDK you are running?

Comment: im using jdk1.8.0_66

Comment: well, the answer below already worked so thanks for the effort, cheers

Comment: Anyway, check if your compiler is defined to compile to 1.5 or higher level. Boxing and Autoboxing should work. But ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple solutions:

- `data.compareTo(this.data) < 0`
- `data.intValue() < this.data.intValue()`

Generally speaking, you can't use `<` on boxed integers.  Additionally, `==` will do the wrong thing, so you should be writing

```
if (this.data.equals(data))
    return this;
```

or

```
if (this.data.intValue() == data.intValue())
```

Comment: @SashaSalauyou because there's no actual reference to, or implicit use of the type, `int` to force unboxing to happen.

Comment: Just tried example close to provided and `<` works okay. Agree about `==`

Comment: What do you mean, "example close to provided"?  Show your code.

Comment: `Integer cmp(Integer left, Integer right) {     
     if (left < right)
         return 1;
     else 
      return right < left ? -1 : 0;
 }`

Comment: Huh.  What compiler version are you using?  It certainly sounds like this doesn't work for the OP.

Comment: 8u73 under Eclipse Mars, compliance version 1.8